# Use of same TaskpaneId for different actions that share the same pane does not work

Tags: xml, excel, office-js

I am using Excel 2016 for Mac my Add-in. After recently upgrading to v16.9 from the previous v15.40 - the action `ShowTaskpane` does not seem to work when used with the `TaskpaneId` tag.

Ideally and previously, whenever `ShowTaskpane` was used with an ID, the panes were shared for same actions. Now it does not.

Has there been any change in syntax or am I missing anything?

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <TaskpaneId>MyPane</TaskpaneId>
    <SourceLocation resid="myproject.url.base.in" />
</Action>
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <TaskpaneId>MyPane</TaskpaneId>
    <SourceLocation resid="myproject.url.base.out" />
</Action>
```

Comment: We're looking into this issue now. Will provide update...

Answer (score 0):

I tried Taskpane ID on Mac and it works on latest version. Could you please paste the entire manifest file to verify what are you missing?